# Writing a contains method in java

Tags: java, arrays, generics, contains

```
package homework1;
//author Kyle Fields


public class HomeWork1{


public static void main(String[] args) {

 int [ ] input = { 100, 37, 49 };

boolean result1 = contains( input, new Prime( ) );
boolean result2 = contains( input, new PerfectSquare( ) );
boolean result3 = contains( input, new Negative( ) );
System.out.println(result1);
System.out.println(result2);
System.out.println(result3);

}



 static boolean contains(int[] array, Condition condition) {
   return (condition(array));
```

}

```
}



package homework1;

/**
 *
 * @author Kyle Fields
 */
public interface Condition {

    boolean makeYourCondition(int[] input);

}


package homework1;

/**
 *
 * @author Kyle Fields
 */
public class Prime implements Condition {


@Override
public boolean makeYourCondition(int[] input) {
        for (int n : input) { 
        if (n >= 2) {            
        if (n == 2) {
            return true;
        }
        for (int i = 2; i <= Math.sqrt(n) + 1; i++) {
            if (!(n % i == 0)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
}
}
return false;
}

    }
```

other classes below

```
package homework1;

/**
 *
 * @author Kyle Fields
 */
public class PerfectSquare implements Condition {

@Override
public boolean makeYourCondition(int[] input) {

    for (int i : input) {
//takes the square root
long SquareRoot = (long) Math.sqrt(i);
//multiplys the sqrt by the sqrt to see if it equals the original
 if (((SquareRoot * SquareRoot) == i) == true){
 return true;
 }

    }
return false;

    }
}



package homework1;

/**
 *
 * @author Kyle Fields
 */
public class Negative implements Condition {


boolean Negative(int n){
 if (n <= -1){
 return true;
 }
 return false;
}

@Override
public boolean makeYourCondition(int[] input) { 

    for (int i : input) {
        if(i<0) return true;
    }

       return false;
    }

}
```

my question is this, how do I finish this code? meaning: what do I need to do for my contains method? (currently, it is telling me the method condition(int[]) is not a valid method in the homework1 class.)

Comment: In the question, those are not methods they are classes. That is the reason that your teacher has put them in `PascalCase`. You are supposed to be implementing an inversion of control pattern not hardcoding methods. For an idea of how this is supposed to look, take a look at the [Guava Predicate](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Predicate.html) and how it interacts with their [Collections utilities](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html).

Comment: You should read the exercise again: you're required to create a class `Prime`, not a method `Prime()`. All those classes should implement a common interfece, e.g. `Test`, which defines a method to check whether a given int (or, in exercise 2, any type) fulfils the class's test, e.g. for `Prime` it tests whether the number is prime.

Comment: You cannot use `new` with a method. In fact, `Prime` and the others should be classes!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about homework. The OP has had one answer that described solution and another that almost spoon fed it. The OP has posted updated code asking for more help. This is not a homework site.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

You can write the code as follow, using the contract of an interface to do the job, look after methods that attend your condition.

```
public class HomeWork {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[] arr=new int[] {100, 37, 49};

        Condition[] conditions= new Condition[]{
                                                new Negative(), 
                                                new Prime(), 
                                                new PerfectSquare()
                                            };

        for (Condition condition : conditions) {
            System.out.println(condition.makeYourCondition(arr));
        }
    }
}

interface Condition {
    boolean makeYourCondition(int[] input);
}

class Negative implements Condition {

    @Override
    public boolean makeYourCondition(int[] input) {

        for (int i : input) {
            if(i<0) return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

}

class Prime implements Condition {

    @Override
    public boolean makeYourCondition(int[] input) {

        //TODO PUT YOUR CONDITION

        return false;
    }

}

class PerfectSquare implements Condition {

    @Override
    public boolean makeYourCondition(int[] input) {

        //TODO PUT YOUR CONDITION

        return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: You have code duplication - this is not what was intended I'm sure. The `Predicate` should just check a _single_ `int` - then the `contains` method should do the looping. In any case spoon feeding the answer to a homework question is frowned upon as the OP will not learn.

Comment: my intention was not do the homework but show another way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

dummy code is fine as long as you know what you're doing.
First the contains() method, it takes an array and a Condition and returns a boolean.  Let's write the signature

```
boolean contains(int[] array, Condition condition)
```

Prime, PerfectSquare, and Negative will be implementations of Condition, i.e.

```
interface Condition {
...
}

class Prime implements Condition {
...
}

class PerfectSquare ...
```

The setup of the exercise hints that in the Condition implementations you should check whether the argument int value satisfies the particular case; the contains() method iterates through the array and returns if it encounters a "true" or "false" if exhausts the list.